# tm.ipc: no such file or directory (socket file to use for the private API / IPC)

Tags: quorum, ipc, constellation

I am following this tutorial to setup a Quorum cluster:
https://medium.com/@shizekun/how-to-set-up-a-quorum-private-chain-with-raft-consensus-and-dynamic-membership-bf826f3927e5

But unfortunately I get the following error at almost the last step, when starting the instances:

```
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
panic: MustNew: Failed to connect to Constellation (tm.conf): Get http+unix://c/upcheck: dial unix qdata/tm.ipc: connect: no such file or directory
```

I don't get when the file `qdata/tm.ipc` was generated at all. I can't find it in the scripts neither: https://github.com/Szkered/quorum-raft-cluster

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was creating the constellation `*.pub` and `*.key` files with a password. If you do this, then later the line `nohup constellation-node tm.conf...` in the `raft-start.sh` script wants a password, but will be put in the background, so you can't type in the password and the process is not being finished